# Internet problem

Tags: networking, internet

A week or less ago I started having connections issues on my laptop. At first I suspected it was the Wi-Fi however the connection is fine on my phone.

I also suspected UFW however I have disabled it a few minutes ago and still had a connection problem.

The problem: I am connected to the WiFi however I don't have internet access. Tabs in the browser don't load

PS: My Wi-FI is hidden but I never had issue.

I purged and re-installed `network-manager` but the issue persists.

Comment: First thing I would try is to _ping wikipedia.org_ to see how far (or short) you get.

Comment: I tried pinging google with no success.

Comment: Do you know of any valid ip address in your lan? Can you ping it? And, what does _/sbin/ifconfig_ tell you? (Maybe your box doesn't even have an ethernet device set up). With common addresses it is hard to tell in case they fail. It may be because of dns-lookup only, or for more basic reasons. You do have a second box, otherwise you would be totally off the net, and hopefully in the same lan.

Comment: Yes, I pinged the internet box both on the laptop and my phone. On the phone it pinged. On the laptop it did nothing then started saying the destination was unreachable.
`From <ip> icmp_seq=175 Destination Host Unreachable`
`ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable`

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence. I m re-establing the connection by turning on then off airplane mode (ie.e turning off then on WiFi and bluetooth)

Comment: excuse my, I'm old-fashioned and do not have what you simple call a _phone_ ;-) . When the network is unreachable, there are several possibilites that I can just guess. What does _/sbin/ifconfig_ tell you? Maybe you're on the wrong network card or something like this.

Comment: When I referred to the phone  I meant I pinged from a terminal on the smartphone.
`iwconfig` shows the right SSID & Access point/MAC address.
Btw, ufw was blocking a lot of "IN" stuff.

Comment: And you can ping the access point by IP? From time to time I have a similar problem that passes away without action on my side. I assume that some neighbor is live-streaming _something_  on my air channel.

Comment: How can I get the IP? Is it the same one shown by the box's OS?
It never happened before. And what do you mean on the same air channel? You mean there's a wifi on the same channel (i.e. interference)?

Comment: If you ifconfig or whatever  showed you the  access point, it should also show you the ip of the access point. And, yes, I meant interference by using the same physical frequency, not using my accounts.

Comment: System asked me repeatedly to convert to chat (or, not explicitly, stop chatting). I think I can't help you much further with my wild guesses. Oh, I see, I'm really old-fashioned, iwconfig doesn't make sense for me as I don't have any wireless attached.